# How should I structure this class inheritance?

Tags: oop, inheritance, coldfusion

I'm developing an application for transferring databases and directories of user-uploaded images/documents from our production server to the development server. The application is written in Coldfusion, but I don't think the language is relevant to this question - it's more of a structural/architecture question than a question specific to the language.

I'll be writing pseudo code for my examples, so please don't pick apart the syntax.

When I've seen class inheritance demonstrated, it's usually something simple like `class Student extends Person() {}`. Obviously, a Student is a more specialized Person, so this makes sense.

In my application, I have a class `Site()` which contains relevant information such as the DSN, file upload directory, etc. I perform my SQL exports in one class and my file upload exports in another class, both of which are called from within the site class(pseudo-code):

```
class Site {
    public function exportSql() {
        sqlExport = new sqlExport(this.dsn);
        sqlExport.createDumpAndZipItAndStuff();
    }
    public function exportUploads() {
        uploadsExport = new uploadsExport(this.uploadDirectory);
        uploadsExport.copyAndZipFilesAndStuff();
    }
}
```

The Site class doesn't do anything other than control the flow of traffic that is requested from the front-end of the application, everything else is handed off to one of the export classes.

This works fine for me, but I'd like to structure it **properly**. Right now, I have to pass Site's properties to the constructor of the export classes, and then set the export class's properties with those arguments. This causes a lot of duplication.

Would it be appropriate to have my export classes inherit the Site class so that I could access the properties directly? The export classes are not a more specialized Site, as in the Person/Student example I gave earlier. Rather, they just perform the heavy lifting for the Site class.

If this is not an appropriate situation for inheritance, how should I structure the application? As I said earlier, the way I'm doing it right now **works**, but I would like to take this opportunity to learn more about design patterns and write my code in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inheritance should be use when something **is a** kind of another thing.

Like a dog is kind of animal, therefor it should inherit from animal.

**Export** is not a kind of **Site**, so it shouldn't inherit from it.

What you're looking for is [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). **Export** should hold a *reference* to a **Site** which it exports. Then you can pass the Site object to it on contruction, and it can get the data from the site whenever you need.

Comment: So, when I create a new Export class from within Site, I should do something like `export = new Export(this);`? And then, within the Export constructor, I should define a property to hold the entire class i.e. `function construct(object Site) { this.Site = Site; }`?

Comment: yea, that's the idea. That way Export knows who he's working on, and you're holding a reference so the data isn't duplicated.

Comment: I think you mean Composition[1] not Encapsulation. Encapsulation is all about the hiding of implementations. Composition is the term for assembling an object from pieces.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Answer (score 2):

Export shouldn't extend your Site class, since things that are Exports are not members of a subset of things that are Sites. Inheritance is overused, and Composition makes more sense in this case as you have done. One way you can refine your existing object model and improve testability is by using Dependency Injection.

Calling "new" inside an object instance makes your object model more brittle and harder to test. You could inject the instances of your exporters into the Site class.

Side note: I named the export classes a little more obviously as *nouns* (SQLExporter, not SQLExport). This is a stylistic thing, but I think it communicates the role of the class better: it is an object that has been delegated the role of exporting data.

```
public setSQLExporter( SQLExporter exporter )
{
   variables.sqlExporter = arguments.exporter;

   // set some properties on exporter here, like the DSN
   variables.sqlExporter.dsn = this.dsn;
}

public setUploadsExporter( UploadsExporter exporter )
{
   variables.uploadsExporter = arguments.exporter;

   // set some properties on exporter here, like the upload directory
   variables.uploadsExporter.uploadDirectory = this.uploadDirectory;
}

public function exportSql() {
    variables.sqlExporter.createDumpAndZipItAndStuff();

    // or maybe your generalize the interface to these exporters and do something like
    // variables.sqlExporter.export();
}

public function exportUploads() {
    variables.uploadsExporter.copyAndZipFilesAndStuff();

    // or maybe your generalize the interface to these exporters and do something like
    // variables.uploadsExporter.export();
}
```

Then, in your main application (or whatever was instantiating the Site object in the first place):

```
thisSite = new Site(...);

// Get some Exporters
thisSite.setSQLExporter( new SQLExporter() );
thisSite.setUploadsExporter( new UploadsExporter() );

// Trigger exports
thisSite.exportSql();
thisSite.exportUploads();
```

This opens the door to using Mock Objects to directly test Site without it needing to have a database or a filesystem to talk to. If you use a DI framework like ColdSpring, the framework could do this wiring for you.

Comment: I see that you are passing references of SQLExporter and UploadsExporter to their relative `set()` functions, but where are the objects actually being instantiated if not from within the Site object?

Comment: Added a little more code to my example to show how that works. It may look like more code at first glance, but the increased ability to unit test each module of code independently from all of the others pays off big time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. Seeing as how Yochai answered the specific question at hand, I'm going to leave him marked as the answer; However, your answer has given me a lot of food for thought and I will probably be implementing DI during a refactor at some point.